# how to set multiple options in post build action -> Build other projects in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, post-build-event

[image]

In above jenkins plugin i have set downstream project to job3 only if build succeeds but at the same time if build fails i want also redirect/downstream other project i.e job4.

can anyone please let me know how to do this? is there any other plugin in jenkins which can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this kind of effect using the Parameterized Build plugin, and a little sideways thinking. We have jobs that sometimes trigger other jobs and sometimes don't, based on the parameters they received from upstream, or that are set by an executing job.

Trigger options include parameter values and/or the existence of a properties file, which a job could create on the fly as needed.

You might have to think through exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish, but it ought to be possible.

Comment: Yes Thank you ... Parameterized Build plugin is working for my requirement. By using  Parameterized Build plugin we can redirect to many projects by just adding triggers.

Answer (score 0):

In your Job4 config, you can set an upstream job under Build Triggers.  You can choose to execute Job4 if the upstream project was stable, unstable, or fails.  This may be too simple for your requirements, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I tried that but my requirement is to redirect to multiple jobs at the same time...Parameterized Build plugin is good option for this.